# What sealant should I use for the base of a sink faucet?

Tags: plumbing, interior, faucet, sink

I guess the title says it all. =) I'm planning to replace my kitchen sink faucet. What type of sealant should I use for the base of the new sink faucet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Many facuets come with a rubber gasket, so you don't need any sealant, just install the gasket.

Comment: Yup, read the instructions that come with the kitchen faucet before you go for the plumber's putty... you might not need any extra sealant.

Answer (score 8):

the old standard is plumber's putty. this can be used on most surfaces and laminates. If your counter top is a natural stone, especially marble, plumber's putty could stain it. Check with the stone vendor to be sure to use the proper sealant that will not stain the counters.

Comment: For the faucets I recently installed, they came with a plastic gasket, but also recommended that plumbers putty be used between the plastic and the sink.

Comment: There are Plumbers Putty formulations that are non-staining (e.g. Sta-Put Ultra).  They are also safe to use on plastics where a traditional oil-based Plumbers Putty would damage it.

Answer (score 0):

Plumber's Putty. Read the manufacturer's instructions just in case. Plumbers Putty is less than 2 dollars at Home Depot so get it just in case (you won't be out much money either way).